# Combining multiple arithmetic operations with regex on columns with Awk

Tags: awk

I need to learn how to combine multiple arithmetic tasks and repeat them for every line of a table, as Awk does. My goal is to count characters of a certain kind in multiple columns, then add/subtract/multiply the values from selected columns (to my liking, which ones), and finally print the original table with an extra column containing the desired results in a coma-separated format. The operations involve counting occurrences of specific characters in the fields. What would be useful for that is a way to store values at every step (line) before printing them.

A toy example:

```
AGCTAGCT AAAACCCC
AATTAATT AAAAAAAA
```

let's make $3, containing A count (#A) in $1, #T in $1, #G in $1, #C in $1
and $4 containing the sum in the number f occurrences of each character in both fields, so #A in $1 + #A in $2 and so on ( I know you can treat it as one field for summation, but it does not work other arithmetic operations, so I would like to separate it this way ).

The expected resut therefore is:

```
AGCTAGCT AAAACCCC 2,2,2,2 6,2,2,6
AATTAATT AAAAAAAA 4,4,0,0 12,4,0,0
```

I managed to do the counting using gsub and regex:

```
cat count.txt | awk -F ' ' 'BEGIN {OFS == "\t"} {print $1, $2, gsub(/A/, "", $1)"," gsub(/T/, "", $1) "," gsub(/G/, "", $1) "," gsub(/C/, "", $1),  gsub(/A/, "", $2) "," gsub(/T/, "", $2) "," gsub(/G/, "", $2) "," gsub(/C/, "", $2)}'

AGCTAGCT AAAACCCC 2,2,2,2 4,0,0,4
AATTAATT AAAAAAAA 4,4,0,0 8,0,0,0
```

However, the summation is not working as expected, as it gives the same result:

```
cat count.txt | awk -F ' ' 'BEGIN {OFS == "\t"} {print $1, $2, gsub(/A/, "", $1)"," gsub(/T/, 
"", $1) "," gsub(/G/, "", $1) "," gsub(/C/, "", $1), gsub(/A/, "", $1) + gsub(/A/, "", $2) "," gsub(/T/, "", $1) + gsub(/T/, "", $2) "," gsub(/G/, "", $1) + gsub(/G/, "", $2) "," gsub(/C/, "", $1) + gsub(/C/, "", $2)}'

AGCTAGCT AAAACCCC 2,2,2,2 4,0,0,4
AATTAATT AAAAAAAA 4,4,0,0 8,0,0,0
```

What is wrong here, and would you have some suggestions on how to do it in a more professional way?

I also tried (this time without summation):

```
cat count.txt | awk -F ' ' 'BEGIN {OFS == "\t"} {NR==FNR; gsub(/A/, "", $1); gsub(/A/, "", $2)} {print a, b, length($1), length($2)}'
  6 4
  4 0
```

but I don't know how to do it for multiple operations on the same field (I would need to store the values for each count/summation/etc. before print).

Thanks in advance for looking into this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first call to every `gsub()` is removing the character you want to count again on your 2nd call to `gsub()` for the same character. Instead of `gsub(/A/, "", $1)` you should be using `gsub(/A/, "&", $1)`.

Assuming your characters are never regexp metachars:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{ print $0, count(1), count() }

function count(fldNr,   numChars,chars,charNr,ret) {
    numChars = split("A T G C",chars)
    for (charNr=1; charNr<=numChars; charNr++) {
        ret = ( ret=="" ? "" : ret "," ) gsub(chars[charNr],"&",$fldNr)
    }
    return ret
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
AGCTAGCT AAAACCCC 2,2,2,2 6,2,2,6
AATTAATT AAAAAAAA 4,4,0,0 12,4,0,0
```

Comment: Thanks, @Ed Morton. As you are dealing with a knucklehead here, could you briefly explain the flow of the "for" statement? I don't understand the meaning of  ret=="" ? "" : ret ","  and "&".

Comment: `( ret=="" ? "" : ret "," )` is just a [ternary expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:) that, in the context of that loop over all characters in the `chars[]` array, is putting a `,` in front of every number returned by `gsub()` except the first one (where `ret==""` is true). `&` is the backreference metacharacter used in every regexp replacement function in all Unix tools to mean the string that matched the regexp. Try `echo "foobar" | sed 's/.b./<&>/'`.

Comment: `ret = ( ret=="" ? "" : ret "," ) gsub(...)` is equivalent to `if (ret!="") ret = ret ","; ret = ret gsub(...)`.

Comment: Why do you have to list the function parameters: `(fldNr,  numChars,chars,charNr,ret)`, even though only one is eventually used in the function call?

Comment: That's how you declare function-local variables in awk, by listing them in the function argument list and by convention you put some white space between the real args and the local variables. Any variable not listed in the args of a function is global.

Answer (score 2):

something like this

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{s=","} 
       function count(d) 
          {for(i=1;i<=length(d);i++) c[substr(d,i,1)]++;
           return c["A"]+0 s c["T"]+0 s c["G"]+0 s c["C"]+0}

          {delete c; print $0, count($1), count($2)}' file


AGCTAGCT AAAACCCC 2,2,2,2 6,2,2,6
AATTAATT AAAAAAAA 4,4,0,0 12,4,0,0
```

Comment: Thanks, this is hugely helpful! By the way, how would you modify such counter function in order to include a negative increment (let's say to increase the count for A's, but decrease for T's)?

Comment: @LechKaczmarczyk for that you have to make the counter conditional, also I guess you want to have the decrement only on the second field.  This may justify a new question with sample input/output.

Comment: What is actually the function of +0 instances in the for loop?

Comment: that's to convert missing values to 0, otherwise it will be blank.

Answer (score 1):

`gsub` actually **changes** the string and **does** the substitutions and returns the count of substitutions that **were made**. So the second time `gsub` is executed on the same string, the substitutions were made, so the is nothing to substitute more.

Use a temporary variable. `tmp = $1; gsub(/A/,"",tmp)`. Or you could substitute the character by itself `gsub(/A/, "A", $1)`.